# Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book page 167

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, kinematics

I am wondering how to get below equation (above eq.(5.104)) on Peskin & Schroeder's QFT book page 167:
$$
y\simeq\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos\theta)\simeq 1-\frac{\chi^{2}}{4}.
$$
Here, the book try to consider an inverse compton scattering (a low-energy photon beam collide with a high energy electron beam), with initial photon energy $\bar{\omega}$, initial electron energy $E$, and label the scattered photon energy $E^{\prime}=yE$. The book use the relation $s=4E\bar{\omega}$ (I thought this already use the approximation $E\sim \bar{\omega}$). Then, to get the expression of $y$, P & S said: "by computing $2k\cdot k^{\prime}$ in the center-of-mass frame and in the lab frame". I am really troubled for this.

Here is my attempt:(initial photon in $+z$ direction, electron in $-z$ direction)

(1) in center-of-mass frame:(as the figure in page 164)
$$
\begin{aligned}
k&=(E,0,0,E) \\
k^{\prime}&=(E,Esin\theta,0,Ecos\theta) \\
k\cdot k^{\prime}&=E^2 (1-cos\theta)
\end{aligned}
$$
(2) in the lab frame:(as the figure in page 162)
$$
\begin{aligned}
k&=(\bar{\omega},0,0,\bar{\omega}) \\
k^{\prime}&=(yE,0,0,-yE) \\
k\cdot k^{\prime}&=2yE\bar{\omega}\simeq 2yE^2
\end{aligned}
$$
then, if we let the $k\cdot k^{\prime}$ in center-of-mass frame equal to that in lab frame, we can get the expression of $y$, but why? here is my puzzle?
(1) why $k\cdot k^{\prime}$ is invariant in different reference system?
(2) why in lab frame we don't need to introduce the angle dependence?

However, that's just my personal thoughts.

If you have any comments, I am really appreciate it.

Comment: Dot products of four vectors are relativistic invariants, no?

Comment: (2) you, the photon, collide with a Mack truck and are bounced right back.... not at an angle.

Comment: @CosmasZachos (1) I agree that dot products of four vectors are relativistic invariants, but here is about difference reference  system. If we look carefully about the $k\cdot p$ in Compton scattering (an example.). On book page 162 figure, in lab frame, $k\cdot p=\omega m$; while in page 164 figure, in center-of-mass frame, $k\cdot p=\omega (E+\omega)$, so it seems that the four vector dot product is different in this two reference system.  (2) for the angle, what really trouble me is that, for my derivation, in the center-of-mass frame, we introduce the angle, while in lab frame, we not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the figure on page 166, in the CM, you have two relativistic invariants,
$$
s= (\omega +\sqrt{\omega^2 +m^2})^2\approx 4\omega^2; ~~~~k\cdot k'=\omega^2 (1-\cos\theta) \approx \frac{s}{4} (1-\cos\theta ).
$$

- In the lab frame, the kinematics of p 162 is very-very-very different, so stay away from it! (The *E* you use is bogus and ***wrong***; use *ω* instead!)

Instead, the low energy ($\varpi$)  photon collides with a basically light-like higher energy (*E*)  electron  and therefore bounces right back (your question 2)
$$ s=(\varpi +E)^2-\left(\varpi -\sqrt{E^2-m^2}\right )^2 =4\varpi E + m^2 +\varpi m^2 /E +...\approx  4\varpi E ; \\
k\cdot k'= 2\varpi yE= y s/2 ;
 $$
so that, comparing the relativistic invariants in each frame,
$$
y= (1-\cos\theta)/2= (1+\cos\chi)/2 \approx 1-\chi^2/4+...
$$

The linchpin of the process is the head-to-head collision of  two light-like objects, the soft photon and the hard electron, a small pellet versus a fast truck. In that frame, as opposed to the CM one,  there is no room for deflection: the soft object bounces right back. (Unlike your terrible misimpression, we actually have $E\gg \varpi$.)

Comment: Why are you using a letter pi instead of an omega?

Comment: @Buzz. I, for one, appreciate how absurd it is, but I respected the text's ill-considered choice (p 167)... I gather Mike gambled that  $\varpi$ looks like $\bar \omega$... The OP knows better, but since this is a "let's read the text together" question....

Comment: Oh, right.  I had forgotten they used that silly notation in the book.